# How to display Woocommerce product price by ID with correct Commas?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I was trying to display the price of a product on a custom page through a short code.

I found this thread: [How to display Woocommerce product price by ID number on a custom page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165014/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-number-on-a-custom-page)

**With this CODE:**

```
function so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => null,
), $atts, 'bartag' );

$html = '';

if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
     $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
     $html = "price = " . $_product->get_price();
}
return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_price', 'so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

**Shortcode:** `[woocommerce_price id="99"]`

I've implemented the code and got it working the only thing now is that the price is not being displayed right it's not registering the commas.

For example I have a price that's being displayed as `$13564.34`

When it should be displayed as `$13,564.34`

It's also doing the same for `$1371.43`

When it should be displayed as `$1,371.43`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT WORKING NOW.

**CODE:**

```
function so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
'id' => null,
), $atts, 'bartag' );

$html = '';

if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
 $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
 $number = number_format($_product->get_price(), 2, '.', ',');
 $html = "$" . $number;

 }
 return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_price', 'so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

**SHORTCODE:**

```
[woocommerce_price id="99"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function number_format() may help. For example:

1578.47 would change to: 1,578.47 after

```
number_format(1578.47, 2, '.', ',');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: I tried implanting the `number_format`

But got no luck.  

I was passing the `$html’ into ‘$english_format_number = number_format($html);`

The number still reminds the same.

Comment: do this: `$html = "price = " . number_format($_product->get_price(), 2);`

Comment: Yeah I did something similar to that. Thanks!