# Display product prices with a shortcode by product ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

IN WooCommerce I am using the code of this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817195/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-with-correct-commas?noredirect=1&lq=1) to display with a short code the product prices from a defined product ID. But it don't really do what I want. Here is that code:

```
function so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
'id' => null,
), $atts, 'bartag' );

$html = '';

if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
 $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
 $number = number_format($_product->get_price(), 2, '.', ',');
 $html = "$" . $number;

 }
 return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_price', 'so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

I have a poor knowledge in php coding. But I've seen that there [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165014/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-number-on-a-custom-page) to display product prices:

```
$_product->get_regular_price();
$_product->get_sale_price();
$_product->get_price();
```

I Have tried to mix these code into the big code, and replaced `get_price()`… It works, but what I want is to display prices is something like this :

[image: What I want to display]

So the Regular price crossed out, and the Sale price next to it, like in this screenshot. If there is no Sale price, it display only the regular price.

Also I have some other problems:

- I need to display the price is in `€`, **not in `$`**, so I have replaced the currency symbol from `$` *(dollars)* to `€` *(euros)* with this code: `$html = "€" . $number;`
- I need to display the currency symbol after the price, like : `37 €` (with a blank space between), not like `$37`.

How can I make it work in a clean normal way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated** *(takes into account if your prices are displayed with or without taxes)*

With Woocommerce there is already formatting price function **`wc_price()`** that you can use in your code. Also you need to get the **sale price**…

To get this working when there is a **sale price** or without it try this code *(commented)*:

```
function custom_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'product_price' );

    $html = '';

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );

        // Get the product prices
        $price         = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ); // Get the active price
        $regular_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ); // Get the regular price
        $sale_price    = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) ); // Get the sale price

        // Your price CSS styles
        $style1 = 'style="font-size:40px;color:#e79a99;font-weight:bold;"';
        $style2 = 'style="font-size:25px;color:#e79a99"';

        // Formatting price settings (for the wc_price() function)
        $args = array(
            'ex_tax_label'       => false,
            'currency'           => 'EUR',
            'decimal_separator'  => '.',
            'thousand_separator' => ' ',
            'decimals'           => 2,
            'price_format'       => '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s',
        );

        // Formatting html output
        if( ! empty( $sale_price ) && $sale_price != 0 && $sale_price < $regular_price )
            $html = "<del $style2>" . wc_price( $regular_price, $args ) . "</del> <ins $style1>" . wc_price( $sale_price, $args ) . "</ins>"; // Sale price is set
        else
            $html = "<ins $style1>" . wc_price( $price, $args ) . "</ins>"; // No sale price set
    }
    return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'custom_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**USAGE** *(for example product ID **`37`**)*:

```
[product_price id="37"]
```

This code is tested and works. You will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, if anyone needs simple text output of prices, is the following:

```
function wc_price_by_id_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'id' => null, ), $atts, 'bartag' );

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){ 
        $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] ); 
        $price = wc_price( $_product->get_price() );
      } 
  return $price; 
} 
add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'wc_price_by_id_shortcode' );
```

The shortcode is then `[product_price id=XX]` (replacing XX with the product id)

To add styling to the price, add a span class by adding the line:

`$html .= "<span class="price_by_id_shortcode">". $price . "</span>";`,

change the line `return $price;` to `return $html;`,

then add your style formatting to your css as needed.

*(N.B. this only outputs current price, not regular price.)*

Comment: A little bit of correction: to add styling the line should be: $html .= '<span class="price_by_id_shortcode">'. $price . "</span>"; (' ', instead of " ") otherwise snippet plugins will parse errors, WP too. And the shortcode should be [product_price id="XX"].
Simple and works as expected. Woocommerce native do not have a price shortcode by default which is unexplained. If you write a blog post and later the price will change you must comeback to all your posted articles to edit the price which is a madness. Instead of price to update itself on your articles if you update the product price.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a friend of me helped me, and gave me the good code. 
If it help someone else ...
Here it is:

```
function so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array('id' => null,), $atts, 'bartag' );
    $html = '';

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){ 
          $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] ); 

      $price = $_product->get_price();
      $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();

          $price_format = number_format($_product->get_price(), 2, '.', ','); 
          $regular_price_format = number_format($_product->get_regular_price(), 2, '.', ',');

      if($price != $regular_price){
        $html .= "<span style='font-size:25px;text-decoration:line-through;'>".$regular_price_format."&nbsp;€"."</span>";  
      } 
      $html .= "<span style='font-size:40px;font-weight:bold;'>&nbsp;". $price_format."&nbsp;€"."</span>"; 
  } 
  return $html; 
} 

add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_price', 'so_30165014_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

bye !

Answer (score 0):

@LoicTheAztec thanks so much for your code!!!

I've done done a few modifications, so I'm sharing it here. Maybe it's useful for somebody too :)

**Note: this version is NOT "plug and play". In other words: it needs some work if you want to adapt it to your needs.**

This version also changes the currency depending on the page language. For example:

- If the page is in English, the prices are displayed in British Pounds.
- If the page is in Spanish, the prices are displayed in EURO.

Note: this version also:

- Removes the css. Instead, it add a class. I did it in that way because I already have my styles defined in that class.
- Add a link in the discounted price to checkout. So if the page language is fr, the result URL will be: https://www.edinventa.com/fr/checkout/?fill_cart=7982

Code:

```
/**
 * Shortcode to display default price and discounted price
 * USAGE: 
 * [product_price id="37"]
 * Original code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237674/1198404
 * Modificated code to fit our needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418231/1198404
 */
function custom_price_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'product_price' );

    $html = '';

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );

        // Get the product prices
        $price         = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ); // Get the active price
        $regular_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ); // Get the regular price
        $sale_price    = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) ); // Get the sale price
        
        // Build checkout URL like: https://www.edinventa.com/fr/checkout/?fill_cart=7982&
        $domain_base_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
        $wpml_language_code = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
        $checkout_url = $domain_base_url . "/" . $wpml_language_code . "/checkout/?fill_cart=" . $atts['id'];

        // Get currency symbol
        $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency();
        
        // Your price CSS styles
        $style1 = 'class="my-discount-price" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none;"';
        $style2 = 'class="my-standard-price" style="text-decoration: line-through;"';

        // Formatting price settings (for the wc_price() function)
        $args = array(
            'ex_tax_label'       => false,
            'currency'           => '',
            'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),
            'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator(),
            'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals(),
            'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format(),
        );
        
        
        // Formatting html output with discount price with link like: <a href="https://www.ed...;" ins class="xxx"> 49€</a>
        if( ! empty( $sale_price ) && $sale_price != 0 && $sale_price < $regular_price )
            $html = "<del $style2>" . wc_price( $regular_price, $args ) . "</del> <a href=$checkout_url ins $style1>" . wc_price( $sale_price, $args ) . "</ins>"; // Sale price is set
        else
            $html = "<a href=$checkout_url ins $style1>" . wc_price( $sale_price, $args ) . "€</ins>"; // No sale price set (UNTESTED)

    }
    return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'product_price', 'custom_price_shortcode_callback' );
```

CSS code:

```
.my-standard-price{
    font-size:200%;
}
.my-discount-price{
    font-size:150%;
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Note: related question to show the currency depending on which country the user is: [Display product prices in the local currency with a shortcode by product ID in WPML WooCommerce Multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63418399/1198404)