# Wordpress / Woocommerce Get single product photo by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to build custom shortcodes for wordpress / WooCommerce, so that I can select just the image or just the price of one single product, because I want to style the product page, but I can't do that with the shortcodes that made by themself...

I have looked alot on google, tryed multiple codes en previeuws but no succes :(

Maybe someone who can help my out??

This is what I have now and this works so far!!

```
//Select just one img from a WooCommerce product.
function singleProduct_img( $atts ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
       'product_id' => '',
    ), $atts );

    return $a['product_id'];
}
add_shortcode( 'singleProduct_img', 'singleProduct_img' );
```

The shortcode I am using is: `[singleProduct_img product_id="233"]` and the output is "233"

Now i want that i can return the image of the product with id="233"

BTW:

Woo = version 2.6.8

WP = version 4.6.1–nl_NL

Any help wil be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [get_the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/):

```
return get_the_post_thumbnail( $a['product_id'], 'medium' );
```

Comment: damn... Didn't think the solution was that easy :( is there also such kind for the $ price of the product?? :o

Comment: Look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165014/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-number-on-a-custom-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165014/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-number-on-a-custom-page)