# How to show a price of a product elsewhere on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to show the price of a product in a post by code using HTML.

I am trying to utilize `$product->get_price()`. however, I need to be able to call the product by identifying it, using its code or something like it.

So Basically, all I want to do is to show the price of a particular product in the post by using a product ID as reference for example.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Woocommerce product price by ID number on a custom page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165014/how-to-display-woocommerce-product-price-by-id-number-on-a-custom-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the product's ID you can use that to create a product object:

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
```

Then from the object you can run any of WooCommerce's product methods.

```
$_product->get_regular_price();
$_product->get_sale_price();
$_product->get_price();
```

Hope this one helps.

Comment: Hi Dipak,
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Should the initial `$_product` information be placed on the functions and the get_price can be called on the HTML?  <br/>
Example:  <br/>
`$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );`  <br/>
Should I specify the product or this function is generic? Should it be like 
 <br/>
'$_product = wc_get_product( $1234 );'`  <br/>
Regarding the '$_product->get_price();'  <br/>
Can it be called on HTML simply like that?  <br/>
`<div>$_product->get_price();'</div>`

Comment: 1st get the product object, then display the price. Here is the tutorial for newbies. [PHP Object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

Comment: Hi Great Dipak, we are trying to understand it... let you know. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

you use **wc_get_product** function :

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$_product->get_regular_price();
$_product->get_sale_price();
$_product->get_price();
```

Comment: Hi
I really don't know how to make this think work... can an example be provided? TX

Comment: Do you mean using the Query Loop (WP_QUERY) for woocomerce?

Comment: Hi, so what we wanted was to be able to bring the value of a woocommerce product. We learned that can be achieved by using a shortcode such as this one: [iconic_product_price id=”4937″].
However, we need to show the product value in a HTML table, and that is where we got stuck still. Any ideas are welcome. Thank you for the support so far.